# How to draw 8 bit grayscale picture on a QPainter by reading the data from a byte array in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a byte (unsigned char) array which contains some data. I have passed this buffer to a QImage and then to a QPainter. But how to get the Grayscale image? I have tried the following code in paintEvent. Please help

```
 QPainter painter(this);
 unsigned char buf[50 * 100] = {100};
 QImage image(buf, 50, 100, 50, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
 image.setColorCount(256);
 QRect r;
 r.setX(0);
 r.setY(0);
 r.setWidth(50);
 r.setHeight(100);
 painter.drawImage(r,image,image.rect());
```

Answer (score 2):

`QImage::Format_Indexed8` means an 8 byte INDEX to a color table, so filling it with 100 means "use index 100 of the color table".

Assuming the alignment requirements are met, you must also do a

```
image.setColor(100, qRgb(100, 100, 100)); // set color index 100 to a "100" gray
```

If you actually only want to fill your QImage with a "100" gray, you can also do

```
QImage image(50, 100, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
image.setColorCount(1);
image.setColor(0, qRgb(100, 100, 100)); // set color index 0 to a "100" gray
image.fill(0);
```

Comment: setColor sets the whole image as 100. I need to color each pixel of the image based on the byte in the buf array

Comment: There is no standard QImage format taking 8bits. the smallest takes 16bits. see the [QImage doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#Format-enum) for the formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [convert function of QImage](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#convertToFormat).  Which format is inside the buffer? Anyway gray is when the r, g and b channels are equals. You can use this fact for an alternative (faster if you know what you are doing).